# Hidden fields don't get updated after HTML form post back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobIndicator)
```

The value for JobIndicator doesn't get refreshed after submitting the page.

I can see the value getting updated when I have it in the display field.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Put this in your controller :

```
ModelState.Remove("JobIndicator");
```

Then your hidden field will be updated.

Comment: I love this answer but I hate this behavior; not very intuitive. It seems to rarely crop up because I'm either changing the field value client-side before I POST back, or I'm creating a new model, but If I set the value I'd like it to get set.

Comment: It helped me to fix the issue by using <input type="hidden" name="Name" id="Name" value="@Model.Name" /> insteadt of  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)

Comment: Why Can anyone explain this.

Comment: @maxspan, take a look my answer

Comment: Why Can anyone explain this. ?

Answer (score 34):

The problem is Html helpers get data from `ModelState` and not from model you pass ***when you call post action***.To solve this, you can call `ModelState.Clear()` in the post action before you return your view, this way the info in the `ModelState` is going to be cleared and repopulated once your view is regenerated.

You can find more info about this issue (and other solutions) in this [blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/20/aspnet-mvc-postbacks-and-htmlhelper-controls-ignoring-model-changes)

Comment: This gets me everytime.

Comment: Having read the linked blog I get the why, but I wish it was a little more obvious that this is how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Ran in to this issue myself. A solution (though not elegant) is to use the basic HTML syntax for this and use the model's value.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="JobIndicator" value="@Model.JobIndicator">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having...

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.JobIndicator)
```

if you enclose the variable in an object it will then work as expected.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeOject.JobIndicator)
```

It Only seems to be that top level.

Answer (score -2):

Just make sure to put this line inside the form tag

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobIndicator)
```