# How to set the value of a hidden field from a controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to set the value of a hidden field from a controller.How can i do this?

In view part i have given like this..

```
 <div>
@Html.Hidden("hdnFlag", null, new { @id = "hdnFlag" }) 
</div>
```

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserName);

Comment: if you are not using model as per your question you can do like this
@Html.HiddenFor("hdnFlag" , new {id = "hdnFlag", value = "hdnFlag_value" })

if you are using model
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.hdnFlag, new { value = Model.hdnFlag})

Answer (score 19):

You could set the corresponding value in the `ViewData/ViewBag`:

```
ViewData["hdnFlag"] = "some value";
```

But a much better approach is to of course use a view model:

```
model.hdnFlag = "some value";
return View(model);
```

and use a strongly typed helper in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.hdnFlag, new { id = "hdnFlag" })
```

Comment: If the hidden field is not updated, put `ModelState.Remove("hdnFlag")` into your controller.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402617/373126

Answer (score 15):

Please find code for respected region.

Controller

```
ViewBag.hdnFlag= Session["hdnFlag"];
```

View

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.hdnFlag" id="hdnFlag" />
```

JavaScript

```
var hdnFlagVal = $("#hdnFlag").val();
```

Comment: Using the user session to store a value may make the application more complex. In the very least you now have to worry whether the value in the session is valid whenever you need to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Without a view model you could use a simple HTML hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="FullName" id="FullName" value="@ViewBag.FullName" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to write following code on controller
suppose test is model, and Name, Address are field of this model.

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    Test test=new Test();
    var test.Name="John";
    return View(test);   
}
```

now use like like this on your view to give set value of hidden variable.

```
@model YourApplicationName.Model.Test

@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Name,new{id="hdnFlag"})
```

This will automatically set hidden value=john.

Comment: this won't compile... var test.Name="John"; ??

Comment: this wont compile becuase  you need an class with a name property

Answer (score 4):

Please try using following way.

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnFlag",(object) Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.page_Count))
```

Comment: This really worked for me. My Application is working like a charm!

Comment: Thank you very much - perfect solution - after a couple of hours of frustration dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

if you are not using model as per your question you can do like this

```
@Html.Hidden("hdnFlag" , new {id = "hdnFlag", value = "hdnFlag_value" })
```

else if you are using model 
(considering passing model has hdnFlag property), you can use this approch

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.hdnFlag, new { value = Model.hdnFlag})
```

Comment: actually the sintax is @Html.Hidden

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to reuse the value like an id or if you want to just keep it you can add a "new{id = 'desiredID/value'}) as its parameters so you can access the value thru jquery/javascript

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Car_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer value from controller using `ViewData[""]`.

```
ViewData["hdnFlag"] = userId;
return View();
```

Now, In you view.

```
@{
    var localVar = ViewData["hdnFlag"]
}
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@localVar" />
```

Hope this will help...